# Rails test failing due to Bootstrap - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, rubygems

I'm following [this](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/filling_in_the_layout#code-rails_default_head) tutorial, and I haven't had any major issues until now, but when I suddenly tried to run the test (Or Guard) it suddenly started failing.

For every failure, it alerted me

```
ERROR["test_should_get_home", StaticPagesControllerTest, 1.3221390806138515]
 test_should_get_home#StaticPagesControllerTest (1.32s)
ActionView::Template::Error:         ActionView::Template::Error: File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-sprockets.
        Load paths:
          /home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/app/assets/config
          /home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/app/assets/images
          /home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/app/assets/javascripts
          /home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/app/assets/stylesheets
          /home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/vendor/assets/javascripts
          /home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/vendor/assets/stylesheets
          /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/jquery-rails-4.1.1/vendor/assets/javascripts
          /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/coffee-rails-4.2.1/lib/assets/javascripts
          /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actioncable-5.0.0.1/lib/assets/compiled
          /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/turbolinks-source-5.0.0/lib/assets/javascripts
            app/assets/stylesheets/custom.scss:1
            app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb:13:in `_app_views_static_pages_home_html_erb___4391039624438268474_46194740'
            test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:15:in `block in <class:StaticPagesControllerTest>'
```

Which I can decipher - It's trying to use bootstrap and can't.

Maybe I'm not familiar enough about TDD but why is it trying to get bootstrap to render a title? Is it due to the partial?

I found numerous other posts with this same issue, but majority either died off, or were from Rails 3 and just restarting the server resolved it.

I was able to resolve it but modifying my Gemfile. I moved `gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.3.6'` from the top, into a

```
group :assets, :test, :development do
    gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.3.6'
end
```

block. I thought that any gem outside of the block is permanently loaded, but is that not the case? Should I stick to this style in the future, also?

(Placing entire gemfile for notation sake)

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails',        '5.0.0.1'
gem 'puma',         '3.4.0'
gem 'sass-rails',   '5.0.6'
gem 'uglifier',     '3.0.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.2.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.1.1'
gem 'turbolinks',   '5.0.1'
gem 'jbuilder',     '2.4.1'

group :assets, :test, :development do
    gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.3.6'
end


group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.11'
  gem 'byebug',  '9.0.0', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console',           '3.1.1'
  gem 'listen',                '3.0.8'
  gem 'spring',                '1.7.2'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rails-controller-testing', '0.1.1'
  gem 'minitest-reporters',       '1.1.9'
  gem 'guard',                    '2.13.0'
  gem 'guard-minitest',           '2.4.4'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.18.4'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

EDIT: Adding in both tests as requested.

**Application Test**

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'
require "minitest/reporters"
Minitest::Reporters.use!

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
  fixtures :all
  include ApplicationHelper

  # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
end
```

**Specific Test**

require 'test_helper'

```
class SiteLayoutTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  test "layout links" do
    get root_path
    assert_template 'static_pages/home'
    assert_select "a[href=?]", root_path, count: 2
    assert_select "a[href=?]", help_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", about_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", contact_path
    get contact_path
    assert_select "title", full_title("Contact")
    get signup_path
    assert_select "title", full_title("Sign-Up")
  end
end
```

Comment: You'r issue starts at `app/assets/stylesheets/custom.scss:1` is there a import directive? How does your failing test looks like?

Comment: @slowjack2k Added the exact test itself.

Answer (score 0):

I observed the same `ActionView::Template::Error: File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-sprockets.` symptom after merging my `filling-in-layout` branch into `master` in [section 5.5 of the tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/filling_in_the_layout#sec-layout_conclusion).

I believe the problem was that Git updated or failed to update some file's modification timestamp. I believe that prevented preprocessor engine in the Rails asset pipeline from updating some generated file when running `rails test`.

I resolved the issue by running `git ls-files | xargs touch`.

Answer (score 0):

Before merging to master branch make a quick check for a running spring server with

```
ps aux | grep spring
```

and then stop it with

```
spring stop
```

or with

```
pkill -15 -f spring
```